# jQuery Cookie plugin license

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I'm currently working on a project that incorporates jquery.cookie.js plugin.
The problem is that the legal team has a problem because they claim its under GPLv3 license but I think its under GPLv2 which is acceptable.

My question exactly is which license does the jQuery cookie plugin ((c)2006) operate under?

Comment: You should probably ask the developers of the plugin, and/or a lawyer. Stack Overflow isn't the place for legal questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery.cookie plugin found at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js is released under both MIT and GPL2 licenses (you choose).

Comment: Thanks, I found this shortly after posting the question.I think is could be safe to assume that the 2006 version is also GPL2